# XeLaTeX fails, claims LaTeX sources older than 5 years

Tags: xetex, compiling

When compiling a LaTeX document with XeTeX, I get the following error:
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
! You are attempting to make a LaTeX format from a source file
! That is more than five years old.
!
! If you enter  to scroll past this message then the format
! will be built, but please consider obtaining newer source files
! before continuing to build LaTeX.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

```
! LaTeX source files more than 5 years old!.
l.545 ...aTeX source files more than 5 years old!}
                                                  
? 
! Emergency stop.
l.545 ...aTeX source files more than 5 years old!}
                                                  
No pages of output.
```

I invoked the command with `xelatex document.tex`, what am I doing wrong? `LaTeX` and `XeTeX` was installed from repos of Fedora 15, how come those sources are too old?

### Edit:

I was asked to provide an example where this error occurs:

```
\documentclass[pdftex, paper=a4, 11pt]{scrartcl}
\title{title}
\begin{document}
%\maketitle
\section*{test}
blah blah
\end{document}
```

I could further simplify, if that helps...

Comment: Please submit your minimal not-working example. :-)

Comment: After changing the global documentclass options (`pdftext` -> `pdftex`; `a4paper` -> `paper=a4`), this minimal example compiles fine. Check for yourself on [ScribTeX](http://www.scribtex.com/account).

Comment: I can compile it without errors. There are only 2 warnings "`pdftext` global options are not used".

Comment: I tried what Werner suggested, didn't help. I changed the minimal example accordingly.

Comment: @Werner What you suggest actually not solves his problem. Any undefined options in `\documentclass` are only unused global options as @xport already showed. The reason you can compile it fine is that you are using a right TeX distribution while @polemon is not

Comment: As this question comes up frequently, see here for a broader discussion: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62829/4736

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing is wrong, except the old software. You should upgrade your TeX Live distribution.

Comment: I found a repo for Fedora 14 providing TeX live 2011. I'll try that out and see if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think this question has been asked by a user using Ubuntu.

The problem is that the TeXlive distributed by most Linux distributions (if not all) is still TeXLive 2007. If everything is from TL2007 it should be fine. But perhaps the maintainer updated some individual binaries, e.g., xetex, without updating everything.

I strongly suggest against using the texlive distribution by Fedora/Ubuntu or whatever. Instead, I suggest you install an up to date TeXlive distribution from the official site http://tug.org/texlive/. You can find everything you need to know about the installation from the same site.

Comment: I think most distros have TL 2009 now.

Comment: @frabjous It seems it is still 2007. Check the following status page. However I use RHEL so cannot be sure which actually shown up in the package manager in Fedeora 16. Anyway last time I use Ubuntu 10.10 and Fedora 14 it is still 2007 https://admin.fedoraproject.org/updates/texlive?_csrf_token=8e1c658f2b88215cd2b6b79760c5646fb093eeb5

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 (lucid) and higher have TL 2009: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=texlive (8.04 LTS (hardy) obviously only has TL 2007).

Comment: It is better to use TeX Live 2011 provided by TUG, not the Linux dist source.

Comment: http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html

Comment: Here's [Gentoo status](http://packages.gentoo.org/package/app-text/texlive) for reference. Green means stable, yellow — testing.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest solution to this problem is to temporarily change the system date (of course, this applies only when actually generating formats, after which you can set the date back).

This , of course, only if for some reason you don't want to upgrade your TeX distro.

Answer (score -1):

I have been using **Miktex 2.6** version on Windows PC. This isn't my original answer, however **it works**. **This message is meant to force people to use later versions**. When I got the above error message **That is more than five years old** the solution is search for the file **latex.ltx** in your latex distribution. Make its duplicate on the desktop or elsewhere. Open it using Notepad. Within the file **Search for the lines** containing 65 as shown below.

```
\ifnum\count@>65
  \typeout{^^J%
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!^^J%
!  You are attempting to make a LaTeX format from a source file^^J%
!  That is more than five years old.^^J%
!^^J%
!  If you enter <return> to scroll past this message then the format^^J%
!  will be built, but please consider obtaining newer source files^^J%
!  before continuing to build LaTeX.^^J%
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!^^J%
}
   \errhelp{To avoid this error message, obtain new LaTeX sources.}
   \errmessage{LaTeX source files more than 5 years old!}
\fi
```

In the latex.ltx file, change **65 to 300 and save it**. Then **replace the original latex.ltx file in the distribution with the duplicate** from the desktop. That should solve the problem.

Comment: Changing `latex.ltx` (which is kind of frowned upon) won't help unless you rebuild the format.