# Line break in table caption using beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, line-breaking, captions

I would like to add a line break in a centered table caption with `beamer`. I can't seem to figure it out.  Here is sample code:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,svgnames,table]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\scriptsize}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{table}
      \begin{tabular}{|c c|}\hline
      a & b  \\
      \hline
      1 & 2 \\
      \hline
      \end{tabular}
      \vspace{3mm}
      \caption{I would like to put a break \newline here in the caption.}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This does not work (unless the caption stretches the whole page, in which case it becomes left aligned, which is not what I want). `\\` produces an error.

If I tried to load the `caption` package I receive this error

```
! LaTeX Error: \@makecaption undefined.
```

This occurs even if I remove the `beamer` caption templates.

Comment: The `beamer` document class is supported by the `caption` package since v3.1 (2007/09/01). So it seems that your TeX distribution is quite old.

Comment: I'm using the Tex distribution currently on Fedora: pdfTeXk, Version 3.141592-1.40.3

Comment: This is TeXlive 2007 which is now over 4 years old. See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24762/latex-sourcefiles-older-than-5-years-old-xelatex-fails

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use a `[t]`op-aligned `\parbox` of fixed width. For example, using

```
\caption{\parbox[t]{4cm}{I would like to put a break here in the caption.}}
```

in your MWE produces

[image]

The same holds if you use a `[t]`op-aligned `tabular`:

```
\caption{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
  I would like to put a break here \\ in the caption.
  \end{tabular}}
```

In the `\parbox` you specify the width, while in the `tabular` you specify the line break.

Finally, there is the [`varwidth` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth) that will shrink to the natural width of a box if its contents is narrower than the width specified:

```
\usepackage{varwidth}% http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth
%...
\caption{%
  \begin{varwidth}[t]{10cm}
  I would like to put a break here \\ in the caption.
  \end{varwidth}}
```

Although I've specified `10cm`, the natural width (which now allows for line breaking using `\\` since the contents is boxed) is narrower.