# How to get minipages in a Beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, minipage

I'm writing a presentation with Beamer and I need the `minipage` package. When I worked on Linux there was no problem: apparently, `minipage` does not exist for Mac OS.

I've so tried to install `genmpage`, but I really can't understand how to use it (I searched some examples on Google but all I can find are documentation pages I'm not too familiar with).

Here is an example of what I used to do on linux:

```
\frame{
\frametitle{Title of the slide}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\hspace{-1.25cm}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=0.55\textheight]{figA.pdf}\\
\hspace{-1.25cm}
\caption{caption of figA\\
\scriptsize\textcolor{red}{[Wu et al., Nature (2009)]}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\hspace{+0.25cm}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=0.55\textheight]{figB.pdf}\\
\hspace{+0.25cm}
\caption{caption of figB\\
\scriptsize\textcolor{red}{[Tizio, Caio et al., Nature (2006)]}}\\
\end{minipage}
}
```

What should I do to solve this problem? Is it possible to somehow install the "original" `minipage` package? And if not, what are the commands of `genmpage`?

Comment: The `minipage` environment is defined by the LaTeX kernel I believe, you don't need any package to use it. Edit: And `genmpage` should be part of MacTeX I think, so you shouldn't need to install it.

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you want to do?

Comment: I simply would like to vertically divide some of my slides so that I can put two figures side by side and some text below each of them (see edited question). Actually, I think that calling the package is necessary, but I am not sure 100%.

Comment: Trust me, you do *not* need a package to use `\begin{minipage}{5cm}...\end{minipage}`. The error you get from that code is `caption outside float`, which makes sense as there is no `figure` environment. However, you don't really need `\caption` here do you? If you remove just `\caption` your code works fine.

Comment: You are 100% right. :-) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is any `minipage` package, but the `minipage` environment is defined in the LaTeX kernel, so no packages are required to use it. The code you show doesn't work because you've used `\caption` outside a floating environment (`figure`), it has nothing to with the `minipage` or operating system.

So you could add a `figure` environment around the two `minipage`s to allow the use of `\caption`. You would need to remove the `\\` in the caption, as that doesn't work, but using an empty line instead works fine. You could also use the technique described in [Line break in table caption using beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44171/line-break-in-table-caption-using-beamer).

However, you could also just ditch the caption altogether. Remove `\caption`  from your code and it compiles fine.

You could also use the `columns` and `column` environments provided by `beamer`. As noted by Ignasi in a comment, if you add `onlytextwidth` as an option to the `columns`, i.e. `\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]`, the extra space seen in the last frame below won't be added, giving a result similar to that in the third frame.

The code below illustrates all these approaches. The `demo` option causes the images to be replaced by black rectangles, so you don't want that for your real document.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Original code without caption}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\hspace{-1.25cm}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=0.55\textheight]{figA.pdf}\\
\hspace{-1.25cm}
caption of figA\\
\scriptsize\textcolor{red}{[Wu et al., Nature (2009)]}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\hspace{+0.25cm}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=0.55\textheight]{figB.pdf}\\
\hspace{+0.25cm}
caption of figB\\
\scriptsize\textcolor{red}{[Tizio, Caio et al., Nature (2006)]}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{With figure environment}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=0.55\textheight]{figA.pdf}

\caption{caption of figA

\scriptsize\textcolor{red}{[Wu et al., Nature (2009)]}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=0.55\textheight]{figB.pdf}

\caption{caption of figB

\scriptsize\textcolor{red}{[Tizio, Caio et al., Nature (2006)]}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Modified version with just minipages}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=0.55\textheight]{figA.pdf}

caption of figA

\scriptsize\textcolor{red}{[Wu et al., Nature (2009)]}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=0.55\textheight]{figB.pdf}

caption of figB

\scriptsize\textcolor{red}{[Tizio, Caio et al., Nature (2006)]}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{columns example}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=0.55\textheight]{figA.pdf}

caption of figA

\scriptsize\textcolor{red}{[Wu et al., Nature (2009)]}
\end{column}%
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=0.55\textheight]{figB.pdf}

caption of figB

\scriptsize\textcolor{red}{[Tizio, Caio et al., Nature (2006)]}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With `columns` environment you can use `onlytextwidth` option to make all columns only occupy `textwidth` with adding any extra horizontal space.