# Beamer Layouting a Frame multiple Minipages

Tags: beamer, minipage, frame

I do try to realize a given structure of a presentation in `Latex` beamer. As a minimum working example I wrote the following code:

I want to structure my frame as shown in the image:

[image: wantedt structure]

The dimensions are mostly written inside the sketched boxes. Some boxes are not fitting the written size. For example, 0.6 (left column) and inside two column (0.3 each). I don't know there would be no space left but for easier understanding I would not choose to sketch 100 percent exact.

I'd try to use `minipage`s with columns. As shown here:

[Creating two columns in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228271/creating-two-columns-in-beamer)

[How to get minipages in a Beamer presentation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170060/how-to-get-minipages-in-a-beamer-presentation)

Neither the use of `minipage` or columns, nor the combination of both worked for me.

The best try I got at the moment is shown in code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Montpellier}
    
    \setbeamercovered{invisible}
}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
    
    \title{My title}
    \author{My name}
    \institute{My institute}
    
    \begin{frame}
    \vfill
    \begin{columns}[T,onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{
                    \begin{center}
                        \small{Example text}
                    \end{center}
                }
            \end{block}
            \begin{minipage}[c][3.5cm][c]{0.3\textwidth}
                \begin{center}
                    \begin{figure}
                        tikz figure
                          \captionsetup{justification=centering,labelformat=empty} 
                        \caption{{\centering \tiny{caption for graph 1}}}
                    \end{figure}
                \end{center}
            \end{minipage}
            \hspace{1.5cm}
            \begin{minipage}[c][3.5cm][c]{0.3\textwidth}
                \begin{center}
                    \begin{figure}
                        tikz Figure 2 
                        \captionsetup{justification=centering,labelformat=empty} 
                        \caption{{\centering\tiny{caption for figure 2}}}
                    \end{figure}
                \end{center}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{column}
        \hspace{0.5cm}
        \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{
                    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
                        \begin{center}
                            \scalebox{0.45}{    
                                \vbox{%
                                    \underline{sdsdsdsdsd}: 
                                    \begin{align*}
                                        K_{index} &=  1  \\   
                                        \Delta &=    1 _{142 }  \\ 
                                        P_{information} &=  1  \\   
                                        \Delta &=   1 _{456 }  \\ 
                                        P_{index} &=  288  \\   
                                        \Delta &=   2 _{789 }  \\
                                    \end{align*}
                                }
                            }
                        \end{center}
                    \end{minipage}
                }
            \end{block}
            \vfill  
            \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
                \begin{center}
                    \begin{tiny}
                        \begin{itemize} 
                            \item adadad  
                            \item sdssdsd 
                            \item sdsdsdsd
                        \end{itemize}   
                    \end{tiny}  
                    \begin{figure}
                    \end{figure}
                \end{center}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \vspace{0.1cm}
    \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
        \vbox{% 
            {\tiny
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item  adsdsdsd
                    \item  sdsdsdsdsd
                    \item  sdsdsdsd 
                    \item  sdsdsdsdsdsd
                \end{itemize}
            }
        }%
        
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

**Problems using this code:**

1. `tkiz` figures are not really centered inside `minipage`s
2. Captions are too far away from `tikz` figure (plots)
3. Captions are not centered (wrong use of centering)
4. The itemize on the right larger block is too small in width
5. The align (math) is too thin

**Additional information:** The given text is example text all text infomation has a bunch more characters in align in both itemize and example text should be header of both `tikz` plots.

I'd appreciate any help, if you need further Information or I did miss anything important just leave a comment.